# Cómo capturar el Token ID con el servicio Firebase Auth de Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, tokens, firebase-auth

Tengo un método para hacer SignIn aprovechando la funcionalidad del servicio firebase_auth de Firebase. Con este método, logro autenticar el usuario y también me permite capturar el User ID y el email dentro de las variables _prefs (de tipo String) como aparece abajo. No obstante, no logro obtener el Token ID.

```
 Future <Map<String, dynamic>> signIn(String email, String password) async {
   
   try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      FirebaseUser user = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser();
      _prefs.idUsuario = user.uid;
      _prefs.email = user.email;

      user.getIdToken().then((value) => _prefs.token = value.token); 
      //Este valor del token aparece vacío

      return {'ok' : true, 'token' : _prefs.token, 'localId': _prefs.idUsuario, 'email' : _prefs.email};
   } catch (e) {
        print(e.message);
        final _message = e.message;
      return {'ok': false, 'mensaje': _message };
   }
 }
```

También probé con:

```
_prefs.token = await user.getIdToken()
```

y tampoco funcionó.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Del `signInWithEmailAndPassword` puedes obtener el result y luego el idtoken.

```dart
   AuthResult result = await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    final FirebaseUser user = result.user;
    final token = await user.getIdToken();
    _prefs.token = token.token;
```

Comment: Gracias, me ayudó a llegar a la respuesta final. Sería bueno agregar que el token termina siendo del tipo IdTokenResult, y por tanto para asignarlo a un String como es el caso de mi variable _prefs, se debe usar token.token

Comment: listo ya aprobé la edición, puedes marcarla como resuelta